# Change button url depending on selected option

Tags: jquery, html

How do I change a button URL depending on the option selected?

e.g.: if someone select "center", the button url will change to "center.html".

I found some examples but most of them it's using value on option field. I tried some of them but didn't work for me.

I tried this so far:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Select below</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">

      <option value="esplande">Esplanade</option>
      <option value="satelite">Satelite</option>
      <option value="paradise">Paradise</option>
      <option value="center">Center</option>

                    </select>

                  </div>  
                     <a href="paradise.html" id="test">
                       <button class="btn btn-danger"> NEXT </button>
                                                               </a>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>



 <script>



$(document).on('change', '#exampleFormControlSelect1', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#test').attr('center', 'value'+'.html');
});



       </script>
```

It's not working, the url don't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on('change', '#exampleFormControlSelect1', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#test').attr('href', value+'.html');
});
```

Comment: You are welcom my dear